# Grid of sent emails on an entities form in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to add a subgrid to a custom entity's form that shows the sent emails that background workflows have sent when certain actions occurred on the form.

How do I do this? Are emails already related to their entities or do I have to create a lookup relationship to the email entity?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regarding (regardingobjectid) field in the email entity. To use this lookup, you need to set the "Activities" checkbox in the configuration of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

When a background workflow (CRM UI) send email for an entity, it automatically sets the RegardingObject as that entity record.

Associated views: You can see the Open items (Draft emails) in Activity & finished items (Sent emails) in  Closed Activities.

You can show the same view or only outgoing emails in a subgrid with little efforts.